# Weird VSync issue in Blender?

Tags: modeling

I got a new laptop with this issue:

[image]

I dont understand why this is happening. The specs of the laptop are completely fine, and this is a new installation of Blender. What s causing this issue?

Its hard to see, but there's basically a weird frizzling and splitting going on through the viewport.

Comment: GPU and driver issues most likely... What kind of GPU and what OS are you using?

Comment: I have a 960M. My previous laptop had this as well, with no issues. There was this viewport issue about a week ago as well, and I updated my drivers a few days ago and it's still happening. I haven't been able to work much as the issue frustrates me too much :(

Comment: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/blender-is-currently-unusable-on-nvidia-gpus-m-mx-family?cb=1

Comment: Oh.. Alright this is a real issue as the driver update actually fixed my performance immensely on a lot of games... I'll look into forcing it to use Integrated.

Okay so I did that and... yes it solved it. Is there any alternate solution to that posted? :/

Comment: Not that I am aware of

Comment: This looks like [screen tearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing) to me, and I was not aware of any sure fix other than getting something like a gsync or freesync monitor.. I've always experienced this off and on, and have just gotten used to it :/

Comment: It is definitely not caused by not having a gsync or freesync :/ Nothing else besides Blender has this issue.

Comment: It's weird, but try not to maximize the window to full screen, or use the fullscreen window toggle...

Comment: Tell me please if this helped